# Format list in one excel sheet to match another sheet

Tags: excel, list, function, sorting

I have two excel documents. In the first document, I have 300 serial numbers in one column, and they are numbered by another column in the order that I want them to be in.

Like this:

```
1   DMPRL9DLH1M9
2   DMPRJ49AH1M9
3   DMPRL5QQH1M9
4   DMPRKDJKH1M9
```

I have a second list in a different excel document. This list also has the same 300 serial numbers, and 300 MAC addresses associated with them.

Like this:

```
DLXRD18LH1MK    A4F1E89AXXXX
DLXRF02CH1MK    A4F1E89AXXXX
DLXRK0C9H1MK    8489AD32XXXX
DLXRL0GPH1MK    8489AD34XXXX
```

I want to re-sort the list so that it matches the first list, so I can then copy all the MAC addresses to the first excel document in the right order. I tried using a custom sort list using the first excel sheet sorted list as the order, but it would not allow me to paste in 300 strings. Any ideas?

NOTE: The serial numbers do not follow any pattern.

Comment: @pnuts - from what I read (and maybe its not interpreting it correctly) `VLOOKUP` should actually work. `=vlookup(B1,Sheets!A:B,2,0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @ScottHoltzman said -
In cell C1 of Sheet1, enter:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1;Sheet2!$A$1:$B$300;2;FALSE)
```

This will look for B1 within A1:A300 of sheet2. It then returns what it finds next to it.

You may copy this from C1 to the other cells within C2:C300.